# call(this.dragger) is not working, d3.drag()

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js, svg

I am integrating d3.js into my angular apps.

**This is my ngOnInit**

```
ngOnInit() {

 this.dragger = d3.drag()
.on("drag", () => this.handleDrag())
.on("end", () => this.endDrag()); 


}
```

**Function that calling this.dragger**

```
closePolygon() {

this.floorOnly.select('g.drawPoly').remove();
var g = this.floorOnly.append('g');
 g.append('polygon')
.attr('points', this.points)
.style('fill', this.getRandomColor());   

for(var i = 0; i < this.points.length; i++) {   

    var circle = g.selectAll('circles')
    .data([this.points[i]])
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('cx', this.points[i][0])
    .attr('cy', this.points[i][1])
    .attr('r', 4)
    .attr('fill', '#FDBC07')
    .attr('stroke', '#000')
    .attr('is-handle', 'true')
    .style({cursor: 'pointer'})
    .call(this.dragger);

    this.coorDinates.push([this.points[i][0], this.points[i][1]]);
  }
}
```

**other related function**

```
 endDrag() {
    this.dragging = false;
 }

handleDrag() {
    console.log('entered handleDrag, will do dragging code here');
}
```

I have problem in ***.call(this.dragger)*** in **closePolygon()** function. Iam keep getting this error

> g.selectAll(...).data(...).enter(...).append(...).attr(...).attr(...).attr(...).attr(...).attr(...).attr(...).style(...).call
>   is not a function

previously when I used **d3.js version 3** ,it works fine, the code is ***d3.behavior.drag()***, but now when I **changed to version 4**, and the new code for it is ***d3.drag()***, my code is not working anymore. Did I called it wrongly? I tried many different ways but still no luck. Or did I miss something?

Thank you.

Comment: Try breaking down the chain into separate calls to see exactly where the problem lies. Don't forget that the evaluation is from left to right, so `.call` at the and might not make sense.

Comment: Hi @Adelin , I have tried so many ways.. yet always getting ..call().. is not a function. I want to enable the user to drag all the created circle (polygon point).. it works in version 3.. running out of idea

Comment: It's hard to tell from where I'm standing. Make one more effort and break that chain into 11 separate statements, execute, tell us the exact line and, while you are at it, also `console.log` the element on which `.call` is said not to be a function. Perhaps, since you call `.style` at the end, you get a style object `{}`, so obviously `.call` will not be a function

Comment: And since you are running in a loop, see on what value of `i` does your error occur

Comment: You put a lot of trust in the fact that `this.points` and each `[i]` is what you expect. I'd validate that bidimensional array a bit

Comment: and yep.. I tried to put .call() before style, and it works.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because the element on which you call `.call` is an object that doesn't have the call property (or it has it, but it's not a function).

How to fix, however, depends on what the issue really is.

However, these are my general suggestions to fix the issue:

1. First, make sure you pinpoint the issue

   1. You are running in a loop, so make sure you know on which `i` your error occurs
   2. Try to break that chain of calls into separate statement, and `console.log` the element on which `.call` is not a function
2. It is very likely that `.call` was intended as per [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) implementation. This tells us the element which that `.call` is targeting should be `function`, so it narrows down what is the expected return value of the chain of calls.
3. You put a lot of trust in the fact that `this.points` and each `[i]` is what you expect. I'd validate that bidimensional array a bit